# Why is router.post(..) not see and router.get(...) works fine?

Tags: express

I have a large express app that I have moved to node 7 and transforming the front end using Angular 2.

All seems to be working, except.... the router.post(...) calls.
All the router.get(...) routes work correctly.  BUT the router.post(...) routes all respond with 404's.

A sample of the routing is as follows:

```
 <routes.js>
  'use strict';

  import errors from './components/errors';
  import path from 'path';

  export default function(app) {
    // Insert routes below
    app.use('/api/logins', require('./api/login'));
    app.use('/api/users', require('./api/user'));
    app.use('/api/version', require('./api/version'));
    ...

    app.use('/auth', require('./auth'));

    // All undefined asset or api routes should return a 404
    app.route('/:url(api|auth|components|app|bower_components|assets)/*')
     .get(errors[404]);

    // All other routes should redirect to the index.html
    app.route('/*')
      .get((req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(app.get('appPath') + '/index.html'));
      });
  }
```

and for example for

```
'use strict';

let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();
let controller = require('./user.controller');
let auth = require('../../auth/auth.service');

router.post('/',  auth.hasRole('admin'), controller.create);
router.get('/', auth.hasRole('admin'), controller.index);
router.get('/clean', auth.hasRole('admin'), controller.cleanDatabase);     
router.get('/user/:sharingFromUserId', auth.isAuthenticated(), controller.getUserSharingFromUser);
....
```

Yet when I do post I see:

```
POST http://localhost:9000/users/ 404 (Not Found)
```

One strange hint in Intellij, suggests that the route.post() is not the correct function???? In the editor, the IDE seems to imply that this is the AuthHttp.post() function which is being used in the webpack section of the frontend.   How can this be???

Comment: What about `POST http://localhost:9000/api/users/`?

Comment: I am in the midst of converting all to typescript files and I am hopeful that this will resolve the issue.  Your suggestion of /api/users/ is not the right direction, since the routing works for everything but POST so, it's related to something else.